# прикрепление файлов к wp_mail()

Tags: wordpress

Может сталкивался кто уже? По какой то причине не прикрепляются файлы к письму. Приходит просто тело письма без файлов

```
$user = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
$to = $user->get('user_email');

$headers = array(
  'From: prost-reestr <info@test.ru>',
  'content-type: text/plain',
);
$attachments = array('https://prost-reestr.ru/wp-content/themes/egrn/static/img/ico-grey-cert.svg');

$mail = wp_mail($to, 'Заголовок', 'тело', $headers, $attachments );    
wp_send_json_success($mail);
```

Comment: Откуда там аттачменту взяться если в заголовках отправляется только текст? Но для начала я бы советовал  выкинуть это всё и использовать правильные заголовки и wp_mail. А ещё лучше - готовые плагины. Да на сервере не мешает закрыть дыру чтобы нельзя отправить почту с левым From.

Comment: У вас хедеры кривые)

Comment: да какие я только варианты не использовал

Comment: И с контентом и без него. и html там ставил данные. И не объект а строку

Comment: И фильтры удалял remove_all_filters( 'wp_mail_from' );
    remove_all_filters( 'wp_mail_from_name' );

Comment: последний вариант $headers = 'From: My Name <test@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";

Answer (score -1):

Может пригодится потом кому не будь.
Тут нужно указывать относительный путь а не абсолютный

```
$attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/static/img/ico-grey-cert.svg');
```

Comment: Чем код в ответе отличается от вопроса?

Comment: Какие глупости..

Comment: А вы знаете чем относительный от абсолютного путь отличается?  В ответе я указал не правильный ответ. а указал в какой именно строке ошибка

Comment: Севлад. 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'; это только для тела письма а не для вложенных файлов. Если вы не заметили то wp_mail и используется. Почту нужно отправлять после ответа с api и ради этого ставить плагин я как то не вижу смысла да и не знаю такой плагин. По поводу дыры в сервере. Спасибо за подсказку не знал про это

Comment: Указание строки, где ошибка - это не ответ, а пародия на него.

Comment: спасибо. поправил ответ